# Display Products On Click of Sub Category in Magento

Tags: magento

How to display products in `on-click` of sub-category in Magento?

Comment: Could you be more precise ? When you click on a category/subcategory link you're redirected to this category/subcategory and you see products

Answer (score 1):

By clicking on a subcategory, the products assigned to this subcategory are visible.
Make sure of the followings:

The product is assigned to the particular category:
[image: edit-product-category]

The product's status is "enabled" and its visibility is "Catalog" or "Catalog, Search":
[image: edit-product-general]

The product's inventory status is "in Stock":
[image]

..or check the value of `Display Out of Stock Products` in `System/Configuration/Catalog/Inventory`:
[image]

And last but not least, if you have multiple stores configured, be sure to make all of these  on the correct store (except the configuration value, that's global).

EDIT: ... and one more thing:

Check the display-settings of your category, because if the `Display mode` is "Static blocks only", it won't display products:
[image]